# Oracle Spatial: Update a numeric column based on Point-coordinates

Tags: oracle, sql-update, spatial, point

(Already solved with a second solution, but I wonder why the first idea does not work).

I have a table with FID, Geom (Point-data), orientation and so on. I want to update the Orientation based on the coordinates, like "set orientation = 99 where X = something and Y = something"

I have this:

```
UPDATE WW_POINT
   SET
    ORIENTATION = 99.9
 WHERE
        F_CLASS_ID_ATTR = 77   
       AND GEOM.SDO_POINT.X = 2695056.511
       AND GEOM.SDO_POINT.Y = 1279718.364;
```

The result is:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE WW_POINT
   SET
    ORIENTATION = 99.9
 WHERE
        F_CLASS_ID_ATTR = 77   -- haltunsgverbindung
       AND GEOM.SDO_POINT.X = 2695056.511
       AND GEOM.SDO_POINT.Y = 1279718.364
Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "GEOM"."SDO_POINT"."Y": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

A simple select returns X and Y as expected:

```
SELECT
    X.GEOM.SDO_POINT.X
  , X.GEOM.SDO_POINT.Y
  FROM
    WW_POINT X
```

So the question is: What is wrong here?

My second solution with SDO_EQUAL seem to work fine:

```
UPDATE WW_POINT
   SET
    ORIENTATION = 389.608
 WHERE
        F_CLASS_ID_ATTR = 77   -- haltunsgverbindung

       AND SDO_EQUAL (
        GEOM
      , MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY (
            2001
          , 2056
          , SDO_POINT_TYPE (
                2695056.511
              , 1279718.364
              , NULL
            )
          , NULL
          , NULL
        )
    ) = 'TRUE';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing both of your queries: the second one (working) has a form `<table alias>.<column name>.<attr>.<attr>`, but the first one is `<column name>.<attr>.<attr>`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> **t_alias**
>
> Specify a correlation name, which is an alias for the table, view, materialized view, or subquery for evaluating the query. *This alias is required if the select list references any object type attributes or object type methods.*

Given this sample table:

> ```
> create table t (p)
> as
> select
>   SDO_GEOMETRY (
>     2001, 2056
>     , SDO_POINT_TYPE (1, 1, NULL)
>     , NULL, NULL
>   )
> from dual
> ```

A query without table alias fails:

> ```
> select t.p.sdo_point.x
> from t
> where t.p.sdo_point.x = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00904: "T"."P"."SDO_POINT"."X": invalid identifier
> ```

And the query with table alias works as expected allowing attribute access in the `select` list as well as in the `where` clause:

> ```
> select t.p.sdo_point.x
> from t t
> where t.p.sdo_point.x = 1
> ```
>
> | P.SDO_POINT.X |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cbf1a4d3b4cff6434aba74079399390b)*

Comment: Thanks astentx
now with alias it works. I tried it already yesterday with alias, but I don't know what was wrong.

BTW: Only the GEOM clauses need an alias; the other clause not.

Comment: @PierredelaVerre This is not an issue with geom, each object type requires aliasing as described in the docs. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=245ef0c97a1ce6a69990a6031ab9158d)